# Export lists to excel

Tags: python, excel

I am a new in Python and I would like your help.

I am creating a script that reads many txt files, removes any numbers, duplicates and at the end creates two lists. One for the words in each txt file and one for the relative frequancies of the words in each file. I use a for loop and I would like at the end of each iteration these two columns for each txt file to be exported in different columns in excel.

Could you please give me any hint? I've read openpyxl and xlwt but I got further confused

Thank you,
icprag

Comment: The easiest way might be to create CSV files (i.e. separate the columns using a `,` or, depending on the system locale, a `;`), if you don't need to add any formatting.

Comment: You already know about the existence of `openpyxl` and `xlwt`, for which there are already various tutorials. You are in effect asking for still another tutorial. Explain what your confusion is and ask a specific question related to it.

Comment: More constructively: it helps if you show your code and describe where you are stuck in it. Also -- the suggestion of @ToJa92 is good. Things like `openpyxl` are often overkill. Excel can easily open `.csv` files

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the SO documentation for Python and Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/2986/python-and-excel/10145/put-list-data-into-a-excels-file#t=201612291516479023817

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

po = np.transpose([List_A, List_B])

# Generate dataframe from list and write to xlsx.
pd.DataFrame(po).to_excel('OutputFile'+ '.xlsx', header=['Column_A', 'Column_B'], index=False)
```